# Is it possible to import data from excel into a SharePoint list, and populate a multiple choice column with the correct data?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, excel

So I have a SharePoint List that contains an ID, and a multiple choice column. Now I have an excel sheet that I want to import into the SharePoint list. However, is it possible to populate the multiple choice column? Depending on the ID number, that data will be different, and I want the correct data choice to be displayed in the multiple choice column when I import that excel table. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to import data into list by using excel, it's impossible to populate multiple choice column.